# BULK insert error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to BULK insert from .csv file and i get the following error:

```
    Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 23 (AR).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 23 (AR).
```

When i open the CSV file in Microsoft excel on row 2 column23 its just the number '0'. 
So if i go manually in my database table and i insert the number 0 in the column AR it accepts it without any problems. I do not understand why this happens. Any help?

Comment: Excel is not a low level editor that can show you the file content, it runs an import. Use a proper tool to inspect the file, even notepad will do.

Comment: In notepad again is 0

Comment: What is the datatype of the column that it's inserting into?

Comment: I think you need change the character coding at target table :\

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code looks something like this

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
{
// Create a reader somehow
IDataReader reader = new ... // <- Your problem will be here
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
}
```

In your reader you need to read the file according to it's type and encoding.
According to your file type you need to select the correct encoding from

```
System.Text.Encodig
```